# no resource found that matches the given name at hint = @string/edit_message

Tags: android

I am new to android, I am trying to create a sample UI which is described in the developer.android website. When I add a edit text, I am getting that error message.

Comment: add your XML file content so it would help others to find what issue you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are currently using this: `android:hint = "@string/edit_message"`, just do like that: `android:hint = "edit_message"`. This is called hardcoded string. Its working, but its not recommended that you make strings this way. The other way is to go to resources, then to strings folder, and there should be one .xml, with strings. To make a new string, just copy the last one, change the name, and the content between `>...<`, where your string should be. To use that string you get it by its name. So if you name it `"myStr"`, to use it in editText, you need to say: `android:hint="@string/myStr"` and you will get the content of the string. Hope this helps. Mark as answer if it does. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the string resource?? To the left is package explorer. Select Your project and go to its res folder. In res folder select values and then click on strings.xml. Add your string resource there and save it. Then I dont think theres scope for such error messages.

Comment: Questions requesting more information should be posted as comments, not answers. Also can you clarify what you mean by "scope for such error messages"?